# how to find dimension of object using 2d image

Tags: image-processing, graphics, machine-learning

Given an image of an object, say a box of some dimension(l , b , h)

Can i use only image to find l b & h ... if not all the three dimension can i be able to find the dimension of side(i.e any two of l ,b or h) whose image i have taken.

Also if i take image from different distance of same object, can i be able to get same dimensions every time. (Given there is constraint on the distance for taking image i.e distance between camera and object will never be more than 200 centimeter).

Can we do using machine learning ?
Or can we use graphics algorithm to find dimension of the object in image and then based on the distance from which image was taken we can have some factors on which we can calculate the dimension of the object.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what kind of box you want to find, and include a sample photo? With a single camera, uncontrolled lighting, etc., you're going to run into several problems.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics takes a description of geometry (plus camera, etc) and generates an image of it. Computer Vision deals with problems of the sort you are talking about: recovering geometry, placement, orientation etc. from image(s).

The first thing I'd say to you is that Vision algorithms are an active area of research, so this is not a stackoverflow question.

However, read up on the following terms to get started:
Image segmentation, Edge Detection, Hough Transform.

Hope that helps!